# Data generation for a zero-one-inflated distribution (ZOID)

Tags: r, probability

I am trying to generate the data which follows the distribution $ZOID(\alpha,\beta,\theta)$ with pmf as follow:
\begin{align}
Pr(X=0)&=\alpha\\
Pr(X=1)&=\beta\\
Pr(X=x)&=\frac{(1-\alpha-\beta)}{2}x(x-1)\theta^3(1-\theta)^{x-2}\quad; x\geq2,
\end{align}

The $Pr(X=x)$ when $x\geq2$ relates to $Geom(\theta)$. I have tried comparing sample mean and variance with theoretical variance for a very large number but those numbers are not as close as I thought they will be. Theoretically, when $\alpha=0.1, \beta=0.05, \theta=0.2$, the $\mu=11.95, \sigma^2=74.85$. Using codes below, for $n=10,000$, the $\bar{x}=12.01, s^2=74.79$. Are these numbers close in your point of view?

I am using R and here are my codes.

```
rzoid = function(n, alpha, beta, theta){
  f <- function(x, theta){
    (1/2)*x*(x-1)*(theta^2)*dgeom(x - 2L, theta)
  }
  pdf <- c(alpha, beta)
  currsum <- sum(pdf)
  const <- 1 - currsum
  i <- 2L
  while(currsum < 1) {
    if (i == length(pdf)) length(pdf) <- i*2L
    pdf[i <- i + 1L] <- const*f(i, theta)
    currsum <- currsum + pdf[i]
  }
  pdf <- pdf[1:i]
  data = sample(0:(length(pdf) - 1), n, TRUE, prob = pdf)
  data
}

n = 10000; alpha = 0.1; beta = 0.05; theta = 0.2
data = rzoid(n,alpha,beta,theta)
```

These codes were initially provided by **jblood94** in one of my previous questions. I tweaked it so that it suits my intention. Are these codes correct and can be used to generate the distribution as above?